# Link with javascript in href and JavaScript support disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, noscript

we have some a link with href made by JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:document.location='http://'+location.hostname.replace('.com', '.co.uk')">stackoverflow uk</a>
```

how can i provide a direct link like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask"> stackoverflow uk</a>
```

when user disable javascript?
I know there is the  tag:

```
<noscript><a href="http://stackoverflow.co.uk/questions/ask"> stackoverflow uk</a></noscript>
```

but then the user will see both the broken link and the correct link. How can i delete the broken link from user interface?

Answer (score 3):

Start with a regular link:

```
<a id="foo" href="http://example.com">example</a>
```

Then bind a JavaScript event handler to it:

```
var link = document.getElementById('foo'); // OR some other means to select the link
link.addEventListener('click', myHandler);

function myHandler(evt) {
    // Do whatever else you want to do
    // ...
    // but don't do the normal link behaviour
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Further reading: [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some psuedo code:

```
<a href="normalLink" onclick="javascript to create link and submit it; return false">text</a>
```

As you can see it uses the normal link that you want to fall back to by default.  When a user has JavaScript enabled, that link never executes as onclick runs first.  The return false is to prevent the real link from being triggered.

Comment: I should mention I posted the old fashioned way of doing it.  Quentin's is better for new code.